# Adding Custom Footer and Header with Laravel Excel Package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

Am using Laravel Excel version 3.1 to generate CSV/XLS etc.
I have to customized my csv or xls to have a custom footer and header spanned through the columns.

Its should look like in the screenshot attached.

[image: Expected output]

Also, I want to store the exported file to storage location but cant make iy work.

And the code I have done is:

```
class ReportExport implements FromArray, WithHeadings
{
    protected $results;

    public function __construct(array $results, array $headings, array $fileAttributes)
    {
        $this->results = $results;
        $this->headings = $headings;
        $this->file_attributes = $fileAttributes;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function array(): array
    {
        return $this->results;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return $this->headings;
    }

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            // Handle by a closure.
            BeforeExport::class => function(BeforeExport $event) {
                $event->writer->getProperties()->setTitle('Patrick');
            },
        ];
    }

}
```

Calling i as below:

```
Excel::store(["1","2"],"xyz.xlsx");
```

How can I add these extra lines to my exported results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Laravel Excel - Extending**
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/extending.html

**PHPSpreadsheet**
https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

There is some room to clean things up, but this should give you the basics.

```php
public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [
        // Handle by a closure.
        AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {

            // last column as letter value (e.g., D)
            $last_column = Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex(count($this->results[0]));

            // calculate last row + 1 (total results + header rows + column headings row + new row)
            $last_row = count($this->results) + 2 + 1 + 1;

            // set up a style array for cell formatting
            $style_text_center = [
                'alignment' => [
                    'horizontal' => Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER
                ]
            ];

            // at row 1, insert 2 rows
            $event->sheet->insertNewRowBefore(1, 2);

            // merge cells for full-width
            $event->sheet->mergeCells(sprintf('A1:%s1',$last_column));
            $event->sheet->mergeCells(sprintf('A2:%s2',$last_column));
            $event->sheet->mergeCells(sprintf('A%d:%s%d',$last_row,$last_column,$last_row));

            // assign cell values
            $event->sheet->setCellValue('A1','Top Triggers Report');
            $event->sheet->setCellValue('A2','SECURITY CLASSIFICATION - UNCLASSIFIED [Generator: Admin]');
            $event->sheet->setCellValue(sprintf('A%d',$last_row),'SECURITY CLASSIFICATION - UNCLASSIFIED [Generated: ...]');

            // assign cell styles
            $event->sheet->getStyle('A1:A2')->applyFromArray($style_text_center);
            $event->sheet->getStyle(sprintf('A%d',$last_row))->applyFromArray($style_text_center);
        },
    ];
}
```

---

**EDIT: Basic page formatting**
Here are a couple of extras to help with output formatting.  These can be appended to the existing *AfterSheet* event.  You may want to open another question for specifics on PDF manipulation.

```php
// set columns to autosize
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($this->results[0]); $i++) {
    $column = Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($i);
    $event->sheet->getColumnDimension($column)->setAutoSize(true);
}

// page formatting (orientation and size)
$event->sheet->getPageSetup()->setOrientation(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
$event->sheet->getPageSetup()->setPaperSize(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\PageSetup::PAPERSIZE_LETTER);
```

Comment: Thanks @matticustard, this looks great. Just wanna know what if I want to make it more dynamic, like if I dont know that the last column is D

Comment: I've added dynamic columns above.  You may want to add a check to verify that `$this->results` is not empty or handle it before it gets to export.  Otherwise, `$this->results[0]` could throw an error.

Comment: Thanks thats good, am also trying to export the same into Pdf with Laravel Excel and Tcpdf.. however the results are very shrinked. Is there a way I can use full page width.

Comment: I have tried $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getPageSetup()->setFitToPage(1); but nothings affecting it.

Comment: I've added some basic page formatting, but I'm not really sure about specific PDF manipulation. You may want to ask about this as another question.